# frozen ground beef

Tags: flavor

I thawed frozen ground beef in the refrigerator over night. I took it out the next afternoon and made spaghetti sauce with it. The ground beef had a frozen like flavor to it. No mold or discoloration appeared but just a weird frozen like flavor. What can I do the next time to take away that old frozen flavor?

Comment: How old was meat? Was it stored properly? etc. Not enough detail to answer

Answer (score 4):

"Frozen-like flavor" makes me think it may not have been properly wrapped/sealed and collected stray flavors from the freezer, and/or managed to get freezer-burned.

I don't know of any way that will "fix" that if it's already happened - prevention is the key. You can try using it only in highly-spiced dishes, if you like highly spiced dishes at all, but it does not really fix it, it just masks it somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the struggle...while fresh is always best for flavor, I totally understand the need to freeze meat...I know alot of people that use plastic wrap or aluminium foil to wrap burger by the pound amd run into the same issue. Personally I tend to always wrap mine in ziplock style bags...I go through more bags this way than normal, however it seems to work really well when I do have yo freeze meat

Answer (score 0):

The only way meat will not have flavor after being frozen is if it didn't have flavor to begin with, or was freezer burnt/not sealed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you to be saying the freezing of already cooked beef resulted in a change in flavor once you tried to use it again.  I have a good amount of sliced roasted beef, left over from a wedding, that I froze (properly in freezer ziploc bags.)  My family doesn't enjoy the flavor that results either.  So far I'm fining only two ideas that might help:  (1) slow cook it in a crock pot, since that method infuses spice flavors into the meat, and (2) use it in a very spicy dish.  This might work,, and I do recall specifically using frozen ground beef in spicy Texas-style chili in the past, which was better, but still not quite like starting the dish with fresh beef.  Finding the solution will save me a lot of cash, so I'm going to keep looking...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not allowing the "frozen flavor" to get into the meat in the first place.

You should vacuum seal the meat and put it in the coldest place in the freezer so the freezing process happens as fast as possible, this will prevent that "frozen flavor".